# I'm not sure how to word this, so my example is below: What is the word for this?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

A friend asks me to watch their pet in the afternoon. I work from home generally but I have meetings with people that afternoon and say I can't watch their pet. The friend then asks if my meetings are at my house or if they are telemeetings.

They're ignoring my response when I said 'no' and digging to see if I'll be at home (in which case their pet can roam around) even though I said I can't watch their pet.

Is there a word for this?

Comment: Yes, you're being *evasive*.

Comment: I don't think Chris is being evasive -- they said clearly "no".  But the friend keeps _**pushing**_ -- that's what we call it when the kids do it -- to try and get around that _no_.

Comment: Chris, you are not being evasive.  Your friend sounds as though "he won't take no for an answer."  But let's not be too hard on him; he may not have a back-up pet sitter.

Comment: @ab2 -- you should post _won't take no for an answer_ as an answer.

Comment: Your friend is being _persistent_ [Continuing firmly or _obstinately_ in an opinion or course of action in spite of difficulty or opposition.] {[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/persistent): emphasis mine}

Answer (score 1):

Your friend ***won't take no for an answer***.  According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/take-no-for-an-answer--not).

> Not accept a refusal, be persistent in demanding something, as in I
>   want you to show me the statements and I won't take no for an answer.
>   This idiom was first recorded in 1930 in Winston Churchill's My Early
>   Life : “Don't take no for an answer, never submit to failure.”

Let's not be too hard on your friend; he probably doesn't have a back-up pet sitter.

Answer (score 0):

Your *friend* is **badgering** you.

> To ask or nag ... in an annoying and persistent way; pester: *badgered the boy into cleaning his room.*

[American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/badger)